# How to control gas discharge rate?

Tags: gas, flow-sensor, flow-control

I need to electronically control discharge of very small air volume over a reasonably large period. Something like discharging 33ml over 15 seconds. I have tried a needle prick hole but it discharges in less than a second. How do I do this? Is there an electronically controlled flow controller in this range? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: A valve ands flow rate mete?

Comment: @winny I already have a valve, but a valve is either open or close. I cannot control the rate of flow. With a meter I can read the rate of flow but not decrease it.

Comment: What pressure in and out? Use a syringe and pump with it, use a "linear" stepper motor.

Comment: PWM the valve? Get another valve?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about electrical engineering.

Comment: @Antonio51 that arrangement sounds interesting, will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mass flow meters (for example by [brooks](https://www.brooksinstrument.com/de-de/produkte/massedurchflussregler) and [bronkhorst](https://www.bronkhorst.com/)) that can easily measure in that range (pay attention, they measure mass flow, not volume! This means about 1% of deviation per 2.7°C and per 80m of height above sealevel)

You might also want to look flow restrictors, for example by [Lee](https://www.theleeco.com/products/flow-restrictors/) or use the adjustable ones used in pneumatics to control the rate at which pneumatics move.

On the websites of those companies you should be able to find all the information you need to get your setup working.